# where to store the azure service principal data when using with terraform from CI or docker

Tags: azure, docker, terraform

I am reading all the terraform docs about using a [service principal with a client secret](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/service_principal_client_secret.html) when in CI or docker file or whatever and I quote:

> We recommend using either a Service Principal or Managed Service Identity when running Terraform non-interactively (such as when running Terraform in a CI server) - and authenticating using the Azure CLI when running Terraform locally.

It then goes into great detail about creating a service principal and then gives an awful example at the end where the client id and client secret are hardcoded in the file by either storing them in environment variables:

```
export ARM_CLIENT_ID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
export ARM_TENANT_ID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

or in the terraform provider block:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  # Whilst version is optional, we /strongly recommend/ using it to pin the version of the Provider being used
  version = "=1.43.0"

  subscription_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  client_id       = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  client_secret   = "${var.client_secret}"
  tenant_id       = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
```

It does put a nice yellow box about it saying do not do this but there is no suggestion of what to do.

I don't think `client_secret` in an environment variable is a particularly good idea.

Should I be using the client certificate and if so, the same question arises about where to keep the configuration.

I want to avoid azure-cli if possible.

Azure-cli will not return the client secret anyway.

How do I go about getting these secrets into environment variables?  Should I be putting them into a vault or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirements, I think you're a little confused that how to choose a suitable one from the four ways.

You can see that the Managed Service Identity is only available for the services with the Managed Service Identity feature. So docker cannot use it. And you need also to assign it with appropriate permission as the service principal. You don't want to use Azure CLI if possible, I don't know why, but let's skip it first.

The service principal is a good way I think. It recommends you do not put the secret into a variable inside the Terraform file. So you can only use the environment variable. And if you also do not want to set the environment variable, then I don't think there is a way to use the service principal. The certificate for the service principal only needs to set the certificate path more than the other one.

And there is a caution for the service principal. You can see the secret of the service principal only one time when you finish creating it and then it will do not display anymore. If you forget, you can only reset the secret.

So I think the service principal is the most suitable way for you. You can set the environment variables with the parameter `--env` of the command [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/). Or just set them in the Dockerfile with [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env). The way to store the secret in the key vault, I think you can get the answer in my previous answer.